# How to express the function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ as a mathematical statement?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I am not that good at creating proofs, but I am decent at coding and was able to come up with this simple "program" that makes up the function I desire:

```
for (row in diagonal) {
    for (position in row) {
        let x = position;
        let y = MaxPosition - x;
     }
}
```

[This is the diagonal referenced above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUrcM.png)

This can be converted into a function within the program:

```
for (row in diagonal) {
    f(x) = (PIR, MPIR - PIR);
}
```

where PIR = position in row and MPIR = max position in row

I realize this is a math question, but the only way that I could think of the answer was in terms of a program.

I also believe the format I am looking for is like this:

```
f(x) = { 
         if x = 0, (0,0)
         if x > 0, (?, ?) 
       }
```

Is there some simple way to convert what I can think in code to an equation?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how to do it, but your function is almost the Cantor pairing function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

Comment: I think what I am looking for is the inverse of the cantor pairing function, since I am not mapping a pair (x, y) to a one value. I am mapping one value (x) to a pair. I have seen that proof, I was just confused as to how the inverse listed there would produce a pair.

Comment: Yes; additionally you're going top-left to bottom-right rather than Wikipedia's other-way-round.

Comment: I understand the situation I want to describe, I just didn't know how to change that from an iterative program into a function. @PatrickStevens by changing the order, would I need to alter the original z equation?

Answer (score 2):

First we look at what number we assign to what coordinates. Since you stated in the question that your function is from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^2$, and you included coordinates $(0,0)$, I guess you assumed $0\in\mathbb{N}$ (which is fine, but not everyone does this, although it's probably quite common in programming). So we start with that.
\begin{align}
0&\mapsto (0,0)\\
1&\mapsto (0,1)\\
2&\mapsto (1,0)\\
3&\mapsto (0,2)\\
4&\mapsto (1,1)\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
Now we look at when our function $f$ returns $(0,k)$. We quickly see that at at $$x_k=0+1+2+\cdots+k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$ we get $f(x_k)=(0,k)$. Now, since the function continues as
\begin{align}
f(x_k)&=(0,k)\\
f(x_k+1)&=(1,k-1)\\
&\vdots\\
f(x_k+k)&=(k,0)
\end{align}
So if $x_k<x<x_{k+1}$, we know that $f(x)=(x-x_k,k-x+x_k)$. But how can we retrieve $k$ knowing just $x$? Equivalent, how can we retrieve $x_k$? Luckily, $x_k$ is quadratic in $k$, so we can solve this kind of equations. We need the largest $k$ such that $k^2+k-2x<0$, so we'll solve $k^2+k-2x=0$. We see that $$k=-\frac12\pm \frac12\sqrt{1+8x}$$ So we need the largest integer $k$ such that it is smaller than $-\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1+8x}$ (note that I chose $+$ for the $\pm$ symbol to get the largest root), and since the floor function is meant for this, we get $$k=\lfloor-\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1+8x}\rfloor$$
We finally obtain the (very, very ugly) function:
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\\
&\left(x-\frac{\lfloor-\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1+8x}\rfloor\lfloor\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1+8x}\rfloor}{2},\right.\\ \\
&\left. \lfloor-\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1+8x}\rfloor-x+\frac{\lfloor-\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1+8x}\rfloor\lfloor\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1+8x}\rfloor}{2}\right)
\end{align}
Please be aware that if you're proving there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^2$ *you don't need to construct this*. I don't know what your purpose is, but frequent use of this function is strongly discouraged.

Hope this helped!