# Prove that $|\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}| \leq |\mathbb{N}|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Claim: $|\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}| \leq |\mathbb{N}|$

Proof:

For all  $ x \in \mathbb{N}, y \in \mathbb{N}$, we can define a function $f(x,y) = x + \frac{(x+y-1)(x+y-2)}{2}$

We now prove that $f$ is an injection. We will show that if $f(x,y) = f(u,v)$ then $x+y$ = $u+v$

Suppose $f(x,y) = f(u,v)$ but $x+y \neq u+v$. Then either $x+y > u+v$ or $u+v > x+y$.

Case 1: $x+y > u+v$

Then $x+y = u+v + \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$.

$$x + \frac{(x+y -1)(x+y-2)}{2} = u + \frac{(u+v -1)(u+v-2)}{2} + \delta$$

Now, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Does your $\Bbb N$ contain $0$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD yes

Comment: For this proof, I prefer using the map $f(x,y) = 2^x3^y$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide I suppose what I wrote actually doesn't make sense

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Lol, I thought of the same...

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632387/how-to-express-the-function-mathbbn-to-mathbbn-times-mathbbn-as-a-ma/1632462#1632462

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you function is an injection, and it's quite an ugly function aswell.

Consider this one:

$$
f(x,y)=2^x\cdot 3^y
$$

Use the uniqueness of the prime factorization to prove this is an injection.

---

By the way, with your original argument, you weren't suppose to get that "$x+y=u+v$" but rather $x=u,y=v$: note that if $f(x,y)=x+y$, then certainly $f(x,y)=f(u,v)$ implies $x+y=u+v$, but this is nowhere near an injection.

Comment: The OP's function is not only injective, but also surjective.

Comment: @egreg Mine? For which $(x,y)$ do you get $f(x,y)=5$?

Comment: I meant the OP's function

Comment: RE: your last comment, in the OP's function the second term is constant under $(x, y) \mapsto (x + c, y - c)$ while the first term changes bijectively, meaning that $f(x, y) = f(z, w) \Rightarrow x + y = z + w$ is enough.

Comment: It's also possible to use a similar idea to get a bijective function:
$$f(x,y) = 2^x (2y+1) $$

Comment: @Farnight Nice, that reminds me of Godels pairing function. E: that's not a bijection tho! It doesn't cover 0.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way of proving that result that's easier to understand:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
1,1 & & 1,2 & \rightarrow & 1,3 & & 1,4 & \rightarrow & 1,5 & & 1,6 & \rightarrow \\
\downarrow & \nearrow & & \swarrow & & \nearrow & & \swarrow & & \nearrow \\
2,1 & & 1,1, & & 2,3 & & 2,4 & & 2,5 & & \cdots \\
& \swarrow & & \nearrow & & \swarrow & & \nearrow \\
3,1 & & 3,2 & & 3,3 & & 3,4 & & 3,5 & & \cdots \\
\downarrow & \nearrow & & \swarrow & & \nearrow \\
4,1 & & 4,2 & & 4,3 & & 4,4, & & 4,5 & & \cdots \\
& \swarrow & & \nearrow \\
5,1 & & 5,2 & & 5,3 & & 5,4 & & 5,5 & & \cdots \\
\downarrow & \nearrow \\
6,1 & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots
\end{array}
$$
There's a first member of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$, then a second, then a third, and so on.  No matter which member of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ you pick, I know, without knowing which one you picked, that after some finite number of steps, I will reach it by following the arrows.

Comment: I understand why this gives the general intuition that $\Bbb{N\times N}$ is countable. I could never understand how this explains that the function is a bijection.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : If you mean the function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$, the fact that it's injective just means if you follow the arrows you never hit the same pair of numbers twice.  The fact that it's surjective means you don't miss any pairs. $\qquad$

Comment: How do you get the formula from the drawing? My students told me it's not hard. I told them I prefer the map $2^n(2m+1)$ instead.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : I wasn't thinking of the formula here at all.  If you want to relate the algebraic formula to the drawing, I'd notice that you have a quadratic polynomial in $x$ and $y$ that has not only an $x^2$ term and a $y^2$ term but also an $xy$ term.  You can find a rotated $(u,v)$-coordinate system in which you have a $u^2$ term and a $v^2$ term but no $uv$ term.  It's start by looking at that.  I worked out the details of this once but haven't look at it for a long time. $\qquad$

Comment: I know it's possible. This drawing goes back to Cantor and so does the formula. But ultimately to prove something is countable you need to show there is a bijection with the natural numbers. So you need something to work with, the drawing is just for intuition that you go in the right direction.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Even if the drawing is "just intuition", that doesn't mean the only way to make the proof rigorous involves expressing the enumeration as an algebraic formula. $\qquad$

Comment: I never said that the only rigorous proof would be to exhibit a concrete pairing function. I said that you need to prove the existence of such function, and you can do it in many many ways (e.g. find an injection and prove separately that an infinite subset of $\Bbb N$ is countably infinite). The drawing is still not a valid proof.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : But the drawing will suggest a way toward the proof. $\qquad$

Comment: To quote Azriel Levy's answer to a student asking about this very drawing today in the exam. To the question "Can I use the drawing instead of a proof?" he answered "Yes, but only if you draw all the infinite graph". I am not saying that nobody should ever use this drawing and we must stone those who do in the town square. I don't see why you won't accept two facts: (1) I find it *personally* confusing; (2) it does ***not*** constitute as a proof, merely as an intuition that the statement is true rather than false. I am going to sleep, since grading exams is my terrible tomorrow.

Comment: Let $\text{“}+\text{''}$ and $\text{“}\sum\text{''}$ refer to concatenation of finite sequences.  Then look at $$ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \Big( (1,j-1), (2,j-2), (3,j-3),\ldots,(j-1,1) \Big) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} \Big( ( k, j-k) \Big). $$ That's not _quite_ the same sequence that appears in the drawing, but it will do the job. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

$x,y,u,v\geq 1$

Suppose $x+y>u+v$:
Then $x+y\geq u+v+1$
So $$\begin{align}
\frac{(x+y-1)(x+y-2)}{2}&\geq \frac{(u+v)(u+v-1)}{2}\\
\frac{(x+y-1)(x+y-2)}{2}&\geq \frac{(u+v-1)(u+v-2)}{2} + u+v-1=f(u,v) + v-1\\
f(x,y)-x &\geq f(u,v)+v-1 \\
v+x-1\leq 0
\end{align}$$
Contradiction. If $x+y<u+v$, do the same thing.

Therefore, $u+v=x+y$

Answer (score 0):

Easier, I think, is to consider $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ as a grid/lattice. Then label this lattice by running along the diagonals, ie $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0),(3,0),(3,1),...$.

Also, Omnomnomnom's suggestion is equally as pleasing.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th odd prime e.g. $3=p_0$ and $5=p_1$. Define 
$$
f(m,n) =
\begin{cases}
p_m p_n & m \leq n\\
2 p_m p_n& n < m \\
\end{cases}
$$

Prove $f(m,n)$ is injective using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (every natural number has a unique factorization into primes).